# List(of String) or Array or ArrayList

Tags: vb.net, list, collections

Hopefully a simple question to most programmers with some experience.

What is the datatype that lets me do this?

```
Dim lstOfStrings as *IDK*

Dim String0 As String = "some value"
Dim String1 As String = "some value"
Dim String2 As String = "some value"
Dim String3 As String = "some value"
Dim String4 As String = "some value"
Dim String5 As String = "some value"


lstOfStrings.add(String0, String1, String2, String3)
```

I would access these like this

```
Dim s1 = lstOfStrings(0)
Dim s2 = lstOfStrings(1) 
Dim s3 = lstOfStrings(2) 
Dim s4 = lstOfStrings(3)
```

if I use List(of String)
I am only able to .add one thing to the list (at a time), and in my function I want to be able to store several values(at a time).

**Solution:**

```
Private Function Foo() As List(Of String)


    Dim temp1 As String
    Dim temp2 As String 
    Dim temp3 As String 

    Dim temp4 As String 
    Dim temp5 As String 
    Dim temp6 As String 

    Dim inputs() As String = {temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6}

    Dim lstWriteBits As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(inputs)


    Return lstWriteBits
End Function
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`List(Of String)` will handle that, mostly - though you need to either use `AddRange` to add a collection of items, or `Add` to add one at a time:

```
lstOfString.Add(String1)
lstOfString.Add(String2)
lstOfString.Add(String3)
lstOfString.Add(String4)
```

If you're adding known values, as you show, a good option is to use something like:

```
Dim inputs() As String = { "some value", _
                              "some value2", _
                              "some value3", _
                              "some value4" }

Dim lstOfString as List(Of String) = new List(Of String)(inputs)

' ...
Dim s3 = lstOfStrings(3)
```

This will still allow you to add items later as desired, but also get your initial values in quickly.

---

Edit:

In your code, you need to fix the declaration.  Change:

```
Dim lstWriteBits() As List(Of String)
```

To:

```
Dim lstWriteBits As List(Of String)
```

Currently, you're declaring an Array of List(Of String) objects.

Comment: Can I access each item like Dim something as String = lstOfString(0) to get the String1 value?

Comment: @BrandonJ I just edited to show your access requirements - that get you what you want?

Comment: Thank you much for your help, but I'm still doing wrong when I try that, and getting a [value of type 'system.collections.generic.list(of String)' cannbot be converted to a 1-dimensional array of System.Colelctions.Generic.List(of String)'] I'm gonna edit my post and show my actual code

Comment: @BrandonJ It looks like your declaration is wrong - you probably have an extra `()`.  See my declaration above for the Dim line...

Answer (score 40):

You can do something like this,

```
  Dim lstOfStrings As New List(Of String) From {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3"}
```

[Collection Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vb.CollectionInitializer);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true)

Comment: "This is the one-liner you are looking for..."

Answer (score 4):

Neither collection will let you add items that way.

You can make an extension to make for examle `List(Of String)` have an `Add` method that can do that:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Module StringExtensions

  <Extension()>
  Public Sub Add(ByVal list As List(Of String), ParamArray values As String())
    For Each s As String In values
      list.Add(s)
    Next
  End Sub

End Module
```

Now you can add multiple value in one call:

```
Dim lstOfStrings as New List(Of String)
lstOfStrings.Add(String1, String2, String3, String4)
```

Comment: I like the *extension method* method.

Answer (score 3):

look to the List `AddRange` method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I don't want to add items to a list when I instantiate it.

Instantiate a blank list

```
Dim blankList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
```

Add to the list

```
blankList.Add("Dis be part of me list") 'blankList is no longer blank, but you get the drift
```

Loop through the list

```
For Each item in blankList
  ' write code here, for example:
  Console.WriteLine(item)
Next
```

Comment: What about ```Dim blankList As New List(Of String)``` instead of yours?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IList(Of String)` in the  function :

```
Private Function getWriteBits() As IList(Of String)


Dim temp1 As String
Dim temp2 As Boolean
Dim temp3 As Boolean


'Pallet Destination Unique
Dim temp4 As Boolean
Dim temp5 As Boolean
Dim temp6 As Boolean

Dim lstWriteBits As Ilist = {temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6}

Return lstWriteBits
End Function
```

use 
`list1.AddRange(list2)` to add lists

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are stuck maintaining old .net, here is one that works in .net framework 2.x:

```
Dim lstOfStrings As New List(of String)( new String(){"v1","v2","v3"} )
```