# Returning multiple seperate SQL values in VB when executing a command that gives many responses

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

If I have a field in a database and select multiple values from that field, how can i split these values and assign each one to a separate variable? I am working on creating a multiple choice question screen for a computing project, so each question will have four answers. I want to create a variable for each answer and store them as strings to be used later, but I am new to SQL and do not know how my SQL command returns values. The SQL code I am using is

```
Dim getAns As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT MCAnswer FROM tblMultipleChoiceAnswers WHERE ChoiceID = ?", DatabaseConnection)
getAns.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("?", sqlID))
getAns.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString()
```

Where sqlID is the question ID. This should return three values (the three incorrect answers), which I would like to split up and assign to three different variables; let's say ans1, ans2, and ans3. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you need to do is store the answers in a [List(Of String)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13274060/1115360).

Comment: Use ExecuteReader instead of ExecuteNonQuery if you are expecting results.

Comment: `.ExecuteNonQuery()` is used for executing NON-queries i.e. an update, insert, procedure call, etc. Depending on the DBMS, that will only return either the number of records affected by your sql or 1/0 for success/failure. If you want to read multiple returns, you need to use the function `ExecuteReader()` and read+iterate the OleDbDataReader it returns.

Comment: Also probably better to use the sql methods instead of oledb.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've tried that and it doesn't seem to work, I don't know if I built the list correctly though so could you perhaps give me an example?

Comment: I have checked the contents of the list at run time and it contains a single string "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbReader", and not any of the values from my database. I do not know if I am using the OleDbReader correctly so any links to how that works would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Are you storing multiple values in a single row (record) in a single column (field)? Not a good idea in DB design as you have now found out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a List(of String) and use [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of ExecuteScalar.  You'll have to loop through the reader to get your values.

```
Dim lstIncorrectAnswers As New List(of String)

Dim objReader As OleDbDataReader = getAns.ExecuteReader()

While objreader.Read()

    lstIncorrectAnswers.Add(objreader.GetString(0))

End While

reader.Close()
```